# bindDN and bindCredentials in passport-windowsauth

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js, passport-windowsauth

What the reason to provide admin's credentials to passport middleware `passport-windowsauth` for authenticating another AD user?

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var WindowsStrategy = require('passport-windowsauth');

passport.use(new WindowsStrategy({
  ldap: {
    url:             'ldap://wellscordoba.wellscordobabank.com/DC=wellscordobabank,DC=com',
    base:            'DC=wellscordobabank,DC=com',
    bindDN:          'someAccount',
    bindCredentials: 'andItsPass'
  }
}, function(profile, done){
  User.findOrCreate({ waId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
}));
```

I think it's not required, `ldap` client can connect with target user's credentials to AD, that means that user authenticated.